# How to access KVM guest from host without having the guest's root credentials

Tags: centos, virtualization, centos-7, linux-kvm, libvirt

I've create a `KVM` Centos7 instance .. i'd like to connect to its console from host but it asks me to enter the root credentials for that guest.

`virsh console test`

Is there any way to achieve this purpose ? or it's not permitted originally ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'virsh console' command simply connects you to the host side of the default console for the guest. For x86 architeture, this will usually connect to the first serial port. Whether you have to enter login credentials or not is entirely upto the guest OS setup. So if you don't want to enter root password, then you need to change the PAM config for the guest OS to stop asking for root password & just give you a shell straightaway.